# Getting NoSuchMethodError: when bootstrapping Objectory

Tags: mongodb, dart

I'm trying to build a small app, for learning purposes, using Dart, MongoDB and Objectory. For that I've created a basic model:

```dart
part of myapp;

class Member extends PersistentObject {

  String get username => getProperty('username');
  set username(String value) => setProperty('username',value);

  String get password => getProperty('password');
  set password(String value) => setProperty('password',value);

  // more fields here
}

void registerClasses() {
  objectory.registerClass(Member, () => new Member());
}
```

And inside my main app file I have:

```dart
library myapp;

import "package:redstone/server.dart" as app;
import "package:objectory/objectory.dart";
import "dart:core";

part "lib/member.dart";

Objectory objectory;

void main() {
  objectory = new Objectory("mongodb://localhost/myapp", registerClasses, false);
  objectory.initDomainModel().then((_) {
    app.setupConsoleLog();
    app.start(address: "127.0.0.1", port: 8080);
  });
}
```

And when I run it I get the follwing error:

```dart
Breaking on exception: object of type NoSuchMethodError
Unhandled exception:
The null object does not have a method 'dataMapDecorator'.

NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'dataMapDecorator'
Receiver: null
Arguments: [Instance of '_LinkedHashMap']
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:45)
#1      BasePersistentObject.BasePersistentObject (package:objectory/src/persistent_object.dart:10:46)
#2      PersistentObject.PersistentObject (package:objectory/src/persistent_object.dart:1:1)
#3      Member.Member (file:///Users/lucian/Projects/dart/eviq/bin/lib/member.dart:1:1)
#4      registerClasses.<anonymous closure> (file:///Users/lucian/Projects/dart/eviq/bin/lib/member.dart:74:45)
#5      Objectory.registerClass (package:objectory/src/objectory_base.dart:118:39)
#6      registerClasses (file:///Users/lucian/Projects/dart/eviq/bin/lib/member.dart:74:26)
#7      Objectory.initDomainModel (package:objectory/src/objectory_base.dart:141:28)
#8      main (file:///Users/lucian/Projects/dart/eviq/bin/eviq.dart:13:28)
#9      _startIsolate.isolateStartHandler (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:216)
#10     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:124)
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are instatiating base Objectory class. There is concrete implementatins of Objectory for server side and browser environment.
Assuming that you are trying to use Objectory on server side you should use `ObjectoryDirectConnectionImpl`

see https://github.com/vadimtsushko/objectory/blob/master/example/console/blog_console.dart for example

```dart
library blog_example;
import 'package:objectory/objectory_console.dart';
import '../domain_model/domain_model.dart';


const Uri = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1/objectory_blog';
main(){
  objectory = new ObjectoryDirectConnectionImpl(Uri,registerClasses,true);
  var authors = new Map<String,Author>();
  var users = new Map<String,User>();
  objectory.initDomainModel().then((_) {
```

Third parameter of `ObjectoryDirectConnectionImpl` constructor command objectory to drop collections after opening db - usefull for samples and tests, you probably should make it `false`

Comment: I tried that but the exception stays the same: ```void main() {
  var objectory = new ObjectoryDirectConnectionImpl("mongodb://localhost/myapp", registerClasses, false);
  objectory.initDomainModel().then((_) {
    var member = new Member();
    app.setupConsoleLog();
    app.start(address: "127.0.0.1", port: 8080);
  });
}```

Comment: I'm using the latest Dart SDK version 1.5.0-dev.4.5 and the latest version of mongo_dart

Comment: have you changed import to `import 'package:objectory/objectory_console.dart';` ? What is your version of objectory? Do objectory samples - first of all `objectory_console` sample run successfully or breaks with same error? How about tests? Specifically `vm_implementation_tests.dart` - server side tests?

Comment: Found the issue: ```Objectory objectory;``` before ```main()``` breaks it. Same thing happens if I remove the ```objectory``` declaration before ```main()``` and then do: ```var objectory = new ObjectoryDirectConnectionImpl("mongodb://localhost/myapp", registerClasses, false);```. So I just use: ```objectory = new ObjectoryDirectConnectionImpl("mongodb://localhost/myapp", registerClasses, false);``` inside main and no other declarations.